# Running docker on private network - CTC1008 : Downloading the debugger vsdbg

Tags: c#, .net, docker, devops

I'm working on a private network and no internet access.

I'm working with .net 8 and docker.

I have moved the the docker images to the isolated network pc.

when i'm running the docker image from the visual studio 2022

it's showing to me this error:

```
1>CTC1008 : Downloading the debugger vsdbg failed. Please ensure that your computer has an internet connection.
```

I have tried to add:

COPY C:/Users/qa93/Desktop/vsdbg-linux-x64/ /vsdbg

But i sill can see this issue

```
1>CTC1008 : Downloading the debugger vsdbg failed. Please ensure that your computer has an internet connection.
```

Is some one tried to run docker on pc without any internet connection?

do you know how to fix it?

Can some one can give an instruction how to run docker with .net 8 and visual studio without any internet? (I don't have any internet access but i can give the images or anything else to Network guys)

Comment: See if following helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the vs2017u5
from url: https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/vsdbg-17-10-20209-7/vsdbg-linux-x64.tar.gz

c:/users/YourUserName/vsdb/vs2017u5/YourUnzipeFilesHereOf(vsdbg-linux-x64)

This is the solution